# Email to HTML in Python

Tags: python, html, email

I am looking for a library which can take a raw email message and convert it to appropriate HTML in Python.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please mention which type of underlying system is for receiving emails.

Comment: @Unheilig Your recent edit really was not helpful.  At a minimum, you should edit out chatty comments like "help will be appreciated"; but when a question is obviously not (any longer?) acceptable as per the topic guidelines, you should definitely nominate to close instead of wasting time on an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices,

If the email has a HTML payload, you can use that - maybe put a simple template together to wrap whatever metadata fields (from, to, subject, date etc.) you need.

If there is no html body, you can just wrap it in a `<pre></pre>` - use the same template.

Sorry, I can't name a library - there is not a lot to do.

What you **can** do is identify an open source app that handles email in a way you like it and take a look at the code.
like this [ppwm at sourceforge](http://ppwm.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ppwm/ppwm/ppwm_backend.py?revision=1.15&view=markup)

Answer (score 1):

Use the MIME package included in email

http://docs.python.org/library/email
Here some examples http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's some [Python code to convert text to HTML](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/19/)